# Unable to access names of a data frame inside an R function

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am obviously making some kind of a fundamental error.
I can't access key data from a data frame argument inside a function,
though the same code works fine in the main program.

```
doit = function(qs) {
  names(qs) # i expect this to print the column names in my data, but it doesn't
  cat(nrow(qs),"\n"); # the number of rows does print correctly though
}

qs_csv <- read.csv('qs.csv',sep=",",quote="",header=TRUE)
qs1 = data.frame(qs_csv)
# names(qs1) # column names print here fine
doit(qs1)
```

Why can't I access all the properties of qs inside doit() ?

Comment: You can. But a function only returns the last statement and `cat` doesn't return anything.  If you want to see the names use `print(names(qs))` inside the function.

Comment: ah, i see -- I didn't realize that the cat doesn't really print, it just returns a value, which the main program happens to print. thanks!

Comment: `cat` doesn't return a value.  `a=cat('foo');a`.

Comment: @Justin You were in fact first with answer. I haven't noticed. So You can post it as answere pointing print and return, and probably user1001630 can accept is as an answer.

Comment: @andi, just undelete your answer. The answers are a minute apart, and I don't think Justin is going to come hunting you down claiming you stole his answer. If there is an accepted answer, it helps future visitors with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
doit = function(qs) {
  print (colnames(qs)) # i expect this to print the column names in my data, but it doesn't
  return(nrow(qs),"\n") # the number of rows does print correctly though
}
```

adding print is enough if you want to display some value while function call.
if you would like that function returns something, that can be used in some assignment,etc. you need to put return statment.